# Get File Created Date from Dropbox JS SDK/API

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I want to extract the file created date from the DROPBOX API using JS. I have tried to fetch the modification date but not able to find the file creation date

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dropbox JavaScript SDK</title>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container.main {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
code, .code {
  font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
  color: #666;
}
.info {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #666;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
a {
  color: #007ee5;
}
input {
  border: 2px solid #007ee5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.button, button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #007ee5;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: #007ee5;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.page-header .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 150px;
}
.page-header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page-header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.page-header h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.page-header .logo {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.page-header .view-source {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.page-header h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/10.27.0/Dropbox-sdk.min.js" integrity="sha512-nTLJySi/DUYzRvvxWOxf31QS5191sN1gpoq6EqGFHPFH0RlM6xOiY6jEp9dmwhDlyFmCmicwLOMnE+fUmo02KQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Example layout boilerplate -->
  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <a href="/">
          <h1>
            <img src="https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/brand/logotype_white-vflRG5Zd8.svg" class="logo" />
            JavaScript SDK Examples
          </h1>
        </a>
        <a href="https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/tree/main/examples/javascript" class="view-source">View Source</a>
      </nav>
      <h2 class="code">
        <a href="/">examples</a> / basic
      </h2>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Example description and UI -->
  <section class="container main">

    <textarea id="files"></textarea>

  </section>

  <!-- Scripts to run example -->
  <script>
    var form = document.getElementById('basic-form');
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = '<TOKEN_HERE>';
    var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
    var filesList = document.getElementById('files');
    var li;

      
    function listFiles(path) {
      dbx.filesListFolder({path: path})
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('response', response)
          var items = response.result.entries;
          var values = [];
              
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i][".tag"] == "file")
            {
              values.push('"'+[path+"/"+items[i].name, items[i].server_modified,items[i].size].join('","')+'"');
            }
            
           
            if(items[i][".tag"] == "folder")
              listFiles(path+"/"+items[i].name)
          }
          document.getElementById("files").innerHTML = document.getElementById("files").innerHTML + "\n" + values.join("\n")
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
    listFiles('')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As Greg answer said, current api doesn't contain that information, imo closest you can get is to look at revisions which are present only up to the version history, so keep in mind its not garanteed to get actual create date. https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesListRevisions

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't return file creation dates (only modified dates), but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.